# Piping in my own C shell

Tags: c, shell, pipe

I've implemented the beginning of a C shell as below. So far I have my redirection working, and I thought I would implement | in a similar way but am having difficulty. 
Can anyone help?
I would begin with checking for the pipe operator, then saving the sa[i-1] and sa[i+1] as the two separate commands, but I'm not sure how to fork() and exec() properly after this.

```
int startProcess (StringArray sa)
{
  int pid; 
  int status;
  int fd1;
  int fd2; 
  int current_in;
  int current_out;
  int fd0;
  int fd00;
  int in = 0;
  int out = 0; 
  char input[64]="";
  char output[64]="";
  char cmd1[64] ="";
  char cmd2[64] ="";
  int fd[2];
  int pipe = 0; 

  switch( pid = fork()){
 case -1://This is an error 
   perror("Failure of child.");
   return 1;
 case 0: // This is the child
   // Redirection


   /* finds where '<' or '>' occurs and make that sa[i] = NULL ,
      to ensure that command wont' read that*/

    for(int i=0;sa[i]!='\0';i++)
    {
        if(strcmp(sa[i],"<")==0)
        {        
            sa[i]=NULL;
            strcpy(input,sa[i+1]);
            in=2;           
        }               

        if(strcmp(sa[i],">")==0)
        {      
            sa[i]=NULL;
            strcpy(output,sa[i+1]);
            out=2;
        }

    }

    //if '<' char was found in string inputted by user
    if(in)
    {   

        // fdo is file-descriptor
        int fd0;
        if ((fd0 = open(input, O_RDONLY, 0)) < 0) {
            perror("Couldn't open input file");
            exit(0);
        }           
        // dup2() copies content of fdo in input of preceeding file
        dup2(fd0, 0); // STDIN_FILENO here can be replaced by 0 

        close(fd0); // necessary
    }

    //if '>' char was found in string inputted by user 
    if (out)
    {

        int fd00 ;
        if ((fd00 = creat(output , 0644)) < 0) {
            perror("Couldn't open the output file");
            exit(0);
        }           

        dup2(fd00, STDOUT_FILENO); // 1 here can be replaced by STDOUT_FILENO
        close(fd00);
    }


          execvp(sa[0], sa);
          perror("execvp");
          _exit(1);


    printf("Could not execute '%s'\n", sa[0]);
  default:// This is the parent 
   wait(&status);
   return (status == 0) ? 0: 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: There are many many questions dealing with this exact problem on SO and other sites. Have you done any searches? If you really want help then you need to ask a more specific question than "I'm not sure how to fork() and exec() properly". The answer to that is that you call `fork` and then `exec`. What specifically don't you understand how to do?

Comment: Yes, I've done a lot of searches. I didn't understand where and when to, and how the STDOUT and STDIN would work with piping.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make a pipe.
2. `fork()`.
3. In the parent set the STDOUT file descriptor (1) to the input of your pipe.
4. In the child set the STDIN file descriptor (0) to the output of your pipe.
5. `exec()` in both the parent and the child.

Do all of this in the child after you `fork()`, just like for redirection.